# Constant "periodization" of a function

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $w$ be a rapidly decaying function on $\mathbb{R}$ such that
$$ \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} w(x+n) = 0$$
for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Does that imply that $w$ is identically zero? What if we assume that $w$ is continuous?

Comment: The sum over the integers is a doubly-infinite series. How are you defining its value? Something like $\lim_{m\to\infty}\sum_{-m}^m$?

Comment: Jupp, for example. But since the function is rapidly decaying, you can choose any enumeration of the integers and end up with the same value.

Comment: Indeed if you assume say that $w$ is also smooth this periodization equals $\sum \hat w(n) e(n x)$, so the condition is equivalent to $\hat w(n) = 0$ at any integer $n$ (so the Fourier transform of any smooth rapidly decreasing function that is zero at integers gives a counter-example and these are essentially all of them).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the **Haar wavelet** is a counter example (i.e. $w(x) = \chi_{[0,1[}(x) - \chi_{[1,2[}(x)$). Decay is arbitrarily fast and mollifying by convolution gives a smooth counterexample.